# Hide vertical bar on the side of tab

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to remove a vertical bar that appear in in the side of each tab i tried it by setting

```
<item name="showDividers">middle</item>
        <item name="divider">@drawable/tab_unselected</item>
        <item name="dividerPadding">5dp</item>
```

but i didn't got any success. See the snapshot the line in the red close region, i want to remove these [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the value of android:actionBarDivider value = "@null". Should work

Answer (score 1):

You may use this two method to remove vertical bars in tab.
Method 1:-

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
android:showDividers="none"
```

add this two line in tab xml.

Method 2:- add this one line in java code

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);
```

Hope this is usefull to you.